# How to use unpacking operator ("*") together with C-style string formatting?

Tags: python, string, formatting

I have recently begun the long, arduous (yet fulfilling) journey of becoming a programmer and am currently trying to get a foothold on the basics of string formatting in the latest version of Python.

In reviewing the 3 main methods of string formatting, I am having trouble combining the use of the unpacking operator (*) with string formatting using the % string formatting operator.

I do not have this problem when using string dot formatting:

```
>>> L = ["Bob", "Frank", "Joe"] 
>>> names = "Looking for {}, {}, {}"
>>> print(names.format(*L))
Looking for Bob, Frank, Joe
```

However, using % string formatting, I get error messages:

```
>>> Names = "Looking for %s, %s, %s"%*L
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> Names = "Looking for %s, %s, %s"%(*L)
SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here
```

Is there any way to combine the unpacking operator with % string formatting, or is this something that can only be used in the context of string dot formatting?

Sebastian

Comment: I'd do `print(f"Looking for {', '.join(L)}")`, personally!  Less typing and it works regardless of how many names are in `L`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%` takes a tuple, so you can write

```py
names = "Looking for %s, %s, %s" % tuple(L)
```

> If *format* requires a single argument, *values* may be a single non-tuple object. Otherwise, *values* must be a tuple with exactly the number of items specified by the format string, or a single mapping object (for example, a dictionary).
>
> — https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting

If you still want to use unpacking `*`, you can do

```py
names = "Looking for %s, %s, %s" % (*L,)
```

although this is just a convoluted way of writing `tuple(L)` in this case; see [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448). Note that `,` cannot be omitted.